# Can you do an 'AND' on a jQuery selector to target multiple buttons?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have two types of buttons that I want to use the same code block. Rather than create two event handlers is it possible to reference the buttons by doing something like this:

```
$(".lb",".da")
```

I tried the specific example and it doesn't work but hopefully it'll give you an idea for what I'm aiming at doing.

Comment: Techically, this is considered an `OR`, since you are looking for either `.lb` _or_ `.da`. `AND` would be selecting an element that had both `.lb` _and_ `.da` (which you do by selecting `$('.lb.da')`)...

Comment: @Vegard I disagree. The question was not "Can I select an object that has both this class `AND` this class". He correctly asked how he could select one set of objects `AND` another set, which we have answered below. If anything its an `AND/OR` scenario.

Comment: @dcneiner - but that's not how programmers talk. "Would you like tea or coffee?" - "Yes." (read: I would like tea, coffee or both, as you have used the `OR` operator)

Comment: @dcneiner - I think I'm saying - 'I would like either tea or coffee'.

Comment: I think it's a 'union'.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, jQuery works just like CSS:

```
$(".lb, .da")
```

You can use commas to use multiple selectors, or a `>` to select a direct descendant:

```
$("#parent > ul")
```

There are many more, but [this page at the W3C site](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) details them pretty clearly. Check out Section 2 for a table with examples.

Answer (score 6):

The comma needs to be inside the selector string

```
$(".lb, .da")
```

Remember the selectors in jQuery are like CSS selectors, commas are standard syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Try: $(".lb, .da") instead, there shouldn't be quotes around each selector.