# Add more different ID or CLASS into same $( )

Tags: jquery

(As I have issues with mozilla, I have to empty FORM after submission.)

At submit I need to empty FORM values. Is there a neater and simpler way of doing this?

```
$('#name').val(''); // empty form input
$('#comment').val('');  // empty form textarea
$('#email').val('');    // empty form input
```

something as: (wrong)

```
$('#name','#comment','#email').val('');
```

Comment: Seems that is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781084/can-you-do-an-and-on-a-jquery-selector-to-target-multiple-buttons

Comment: Yes it is! But this question never appeared in my researches. I'd never ask something like with the word terms used there. And there is the @jAndy's answer!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plain form [`.reset()`<sup>help</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.reset) method is there for you. Since this method is a native "DOM" method from `HTMLInputElement` you need to grab the `DOMNode` from the jQuery object. That can be accomplished by invoking [`.get(0)`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/get/) (which grabs the first element from the jQuery array-like-object) or just access it with brackets.

```
$('form')[0].reset();
```

**demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/53SRZ/

Another option is to use a selector like

```
$('form input').val('');
```

If you don't have the requirement to only clear specific elements.

Comment: This sets the value to whatever was defined by the HTML, not to a blank value.

Comment: @BoltClock: true, but it's probably way more elegant if the default values are empty.

Comment: WOW! This is MEGA GREAT! May you just please explain the [0]. Thanks! It represents the **'all inside'** the form? Right?

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is nice and complete! Elegant as all your answers.

Answer (score 2):

You use the comma to separate not your function arguments but your selectors. All your selectors go in one string argument:

```
$('#name, #comment, #email').val('');
```

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

```
$('#name','#comment','#email').val('');
```

Close, but not quite. The correct solution is simply to put them all into the same string, like this:

```
$('#name, #comment, #email').val('');
```

Comment: hahaha I knew it and think'd I've tryed it... guess i had some errors. THANKS! That's it!

Answer (score 2):

Try `$('#name, #comment, #email').val('');`.

The quotations are supposed to enclose EVERYTHING you're selecting. You're telling jQuery what is essentially a CSS selection, and the whole block `#name, #comment, #email` is a valid CSS selector.

Comment: Yes yes. THANKS! I told I should never again work late in the night.